# And not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a collection named student like

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5693b549c4fd0e0bf4782d73"),
        "nameIdentity" : [
                {
                        "name" : "a"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "b"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5693b549c4fd0e0bf4782d74"),
        "nameIdentity" : [
                {
                        "name" : "a"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5693b549c4fd0e0bf4782d75"),
        "nameIdentity" : [
                {
                        "name" : "a"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "b"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5693b549c4fd0e0bf4782d76"),
        "nameIdentity" : [
                {
                        "name" : "b"
                }
        ]
}
```

i am trying to query using 'and' but its giving me some different output.

When i query for all the nameIdentities which has only name "a" `db.student.find({"nameIdentity.name":"a"})` i am expecting the output as 1 where as i am getting 3. Again when i query for names with both a and b `db.student.find({"nameIdentity.name":"a"},{"nameIdentity.sourceReferenceId.sourceName":"b"})` i am expecting output as 2 but i am getting 4. Can any one suggest me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this.

```
db.student.find({"nameIdentity.name":"a","nameIdentity": { $size: 1 }})
```

Answer (score 0):

in your query 
`db.student.find({"nameIdentity.name":"a"})` you are searching for data which nameIdentity is "a" not only a.  and in your second query use like
`db.student.find({"nameIdentity.name":"a","nameIdentity.name":"b"})`

Comment: How do i query and get only documents which have a as name?

Comment: The solution which u gave is also not working again i am getting unmatched output

Comment: tell exactly what you want to search?

Comment: i would like to search documents which has only name as 'a', if it has 'b' as well then it should not search. Here my name identity is an array of name documents

Comment: use this... db.student.find({"nameIdentity.name":"a","nameIdentity": { $size: 1 }})